# Automapper: how to map nested object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am struggling with the Automapper syntax.
I have a List of PropertySurveys, each containing 1 Property.
I wish to map each item on the collection into a new object which combines the 2 classes.

So my code looks like;

```
            var propertySurveys = new List<PropertyToSurveyOutput >();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<Property, PropertyToSurveyOutput >();
                var property = Mapper.Map<PropertyToSurvey>(item.Property);
                Mapper.CreateMap<PropertySurvey, PropertyToSurveyOutput >();
                property = Mapper.Map<PropertyToSurvey>(item);
                propertySurveys.Add(property);
            }
```

My simplified classes look like;

```
public class Property
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class PropertySurvey
{
    public string PropertySurveyName { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set;}
}

public class PropertyToSurveyOutput
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertySurveyName { get; set; }
}
```

So in the PropertyToSurveyOutput object, after the first mapping PropertyName is set. Then after the second mapping PropertySurveyName is set, but PropertyName is overridden to null.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can u please post simplified class definitions instead of verbal description? Also it's not clear what is `items`

Comment: Are Property and PropertySurvey properties of some other class which is represented by item? Or is PropertySurvey the parent object?  As Sergey said, we really need a class diagram here...

Comment: I have put in the simplified classes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, Automapper supports mapping of collections. You don't need to map each item in a loop.

Second - you don't need to re-create map each time you need to map single object. Put mappings creation to application start code (or before first usage of mapping).

And last - with Automapper you can create mapping and define how to do custom map for some properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PropertySurvey, PropertyToSurveyOutput>()
   .ForMember(pts => pts.PropertyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(ps => ps.Property.PropertyName));
```

Usage:

```
var items = new List<PropertySurvey>
{
    new PropertySurvey { 
          PropertySurveyName = "Foo", 
          Property = new Property { PropertyName = "X" } },
    new PropertySurvey { 
          PropertySurveyName = "Bar", 
          Property = new Property { PropertyName = "Y" } }
};

var propertySurveys = Mapper.Map<List<PropertyToSurveyOutput>>(items);
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "PropertyName": "X",
    "PropertySurveyName": "Foo"
  },
  {
    "PropertyName": "Y",
    "PropertySurveyName": "Bar"
  }
]
```

---

UPDATE: If your `Property` class has many properties, you can define two default mappings - one from `Property`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Property, PropertyToSurveyOutput>();
```

And one from `PropertySurvey`. And use first mapping after you used mapping from `PropertySurvey`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PropertySurvey, PropertyToSurveyOutput>()
      .AfterMap((ps, pst) => Mapper.Map(ps.Property, pst));
```

Comment: The classes I specified were simplified. If there are 10 fields in Property I want to map to PropertyToSurveyOutput do I have to specify each one, even if the name of the field is the same?

Comment: @arame3333 answer updated. In case you need to map two complex objects into one, you need two mappings - one from Property and one from PropertySurvey

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for!

Comment: The last line is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since v8.1 you can use the [`IncludeMemebers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers) method in your configuration to map nested objects using existing mappings.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Property, PropertyToSurveyOutput>();
cfg.CreateMap<PropertySurvey, PropertyToSurveyOutput>()
  .IncludeMembers(src => src.Property);
```

Comment: I'm using AutoMapper 12 and the accepted answer didn't work for me, because I can't access a Mapper when configuring a Profile. This answer is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score -5):

First rule of automapper property name should be same then only it will map correctly and assign the value but in your case one property name is only "Property" and second property name is "PropertyName" so make property name same  it will work for you

Comment: Incorrect. You can specify which property should map to which.