# Automapper and mapping complex collections

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I have a question about automapper, thing is I have a model that has nested collection of other models, and models in that collection also has a collection of models something like (DB model):

```
public class Cabin 
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public Rack[] Racks { get; set; }
}

public class Rack
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string RackName { get; set; }
    public IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public Module[] Modules { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
}
```

Well from Dto side I have something like:

```
public class CabinDto 
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RackDto[] Racks { get; set; }
}

public class RackDto
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ModuleDto[] Modules{ get; set; }
}

public class ModuleDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to map it all at once, but figure out a way to map a list object with different properties names.

For main class I have:

```
CreateMap<Db.Cabin, Dto.Cabin>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
  // how to map nested list
```

I could just add some method that assigns values and map to this method, but it does not feel right. I looked in documentation and there are only examples with simple collection with same name lists.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: how to map nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271334/automapper-how-to-map-nested-object)

Comment: Well not quite duplicate in that answer you got simple nested object mapped to property, here I have nested collections with nested collections, more complicated I think.

Comment: I think Automapper handles it the same way. Were you able to try my answer?

Comment: Aye additional mapping did not worked, it stayed null after mapping was done

Comment: That's strange because it's working when I test it, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLtDU8

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add mapping for the type in the nested list and AutoMapper will take care of it.

```
CreateMap<Db.Module, Dto.Module>();
CreateMap<Db.Rack, Dto.Rack>();
```

Also when the name of properties in source and origin are the same, you don't need to call the `ForMember()` method.
So in your case you need it for the `ModuleName` to `Name` of the `Module` to `ModuleDto` mapping, and same for the `Rack` class, see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLtDU8).